# Calling events after a specified interval of time

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

So here is the breakdown of my program. It is a tool that measures latency to a server on a specified port.

So currently I have a manual check to find the server on a specific port. Then I ping this server every 500 ms and update some GUI elements based on this ping.

I have the pinging done in a background thread and I call thread.sleep(500) after every ping.

Would it be better to use timers for these events?

I want to check for the server every 5 seconds, and ping every 500 ms.

Comment: "Would it be better.."  Define 'better".  In general, what ever accomplishes your task in the simplest, most maintainable way possible, is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 timers. Sleeping the thread is terrible performance. When the 5 second timer executes, disable the 500 ms timer. When it is done executing, enable it. This is the simplest and most effective way of doing it, IMO.

Or, don't disable the timer if that doesn't matter. Just keep both going and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Task Scheduler api and setup one time task that will start app after next 5 seconds.Nice managed wrraper: taskscheduler.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

When you use sleep, it doesn't matter how long your task takes.  Sleep 500ms, do a 5 hour task, and then sleep again.

If you use timers, you have to deal with the possibility your task may overlap the firing of the next timer event.   Which makes things more complicated.